# Datetime formatting in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have DateTime datatype in C# and Sql server as well.
Now, while inserting a value its trying to insert "12-08-2015 23:06:10" but Sql Server accepts datetime in 12 hourse format. So, its throwing error.

I tried the following ways to convert the date:

1) `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));`

2) `Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0:G}",DateTime.Now));`

I need the datetime in the below format:
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" AM / PM

Any help would be appreciated.

The whole code is given below:

**Entity Class**

```
[Table("TB_USERS")]
public class Users_mast
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }

    [Column (TypeName="VARCHAR")]
    [MaxLength (15)]
    [Required]
    public string user_fname { get; set; }

    [Column (TypeName="VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength (10,MinimumLength=1)]
    public string user_mname { get; set; } // middle name

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Required]
    public string user_lname { get; set; }

    [Column (TypeName="VARCHAR")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string user_email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string user_mobile { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(10,MinimumLength=6)]
    [Required]
    public string pwd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_modified_date { get; set; } // can be NULL

    [Column (TypeName="VARBINARY(MAX)")]
    public byte[] user_image { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool status { get; set; } // Active | Inactive (1 | 0 )
}
```

**Context Class**

```
public class context : DbContext
{
    public context()
        : base("name=sqlConn")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Users_mast> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Finally, the calling class**

```
public class test_try
{
    context obj = new context();

    public void add()
    {
        obj.Users.Add(new Users_mast() {user_fname="Agnib", user_lname="Pyne", user_email="a@gmail.com", user_mobile="9830972301", username="agnib", pwd="As1232", created_date=DateTime.Now, status=true });
        obj.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In the calling class, "created_date=DateTime.Now" throwing error.

Please help.

Comment: can you show the exception that is being thrown when you attempt to insert the records with the invalid datetime?

Comment: can you also show the code you are using when inserting the datetime values to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about the date format. Just add the parameter as a Date type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

I'm assuming you are using parameters, which you should, to avoid SQL Injection problems.

Edit: as I'm seeing the other answers, please, don't convert a Date to string in order to insert it in the DB, it's not needed.

Comment: Actually, I am using Entity Framework - Code First methodology. I was just testing with dummy data simply by passing values directly. Anyways, I will try out using parameters.

Comment: @Agnib you can't expect us to guess what your problem is if you won't show code.

Comment: @Agnib, if you are still having issues, update your question with the code you are using.

Comment: Ok. I will update the question with code. Thank you.

Comment: @Agnib, unfortunately I can't test the code now, but have you tried specifying the data type of the column as you are doing for the rest of the properties?

Comment: @Charmander - Actually, I am new into Entity Framework and read in the internet that we need to specfify the "DataType" attribute if the datatype of c# does not match with the sql. For Example: if I write "String Name" and don't specify the "DataType", it will automatically create the name column in sql as "NVarchar" but if I want it as "Varchar", then I need to specify the column DataType what I want in Sql server. So, as because the "Created_By" is already a "DateTime" column in C# and I want the column as "DateTime" in Sql also, i did not mention the "DatatType" attribute.

Comment: @Agnib, as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx), there are multiple data types for dates in SQL Server. So, please give it a try specifying the exact data type in your C# code.

Comment: Ok. Sure. I will give a try then and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below to display a datetime as a 12 hour clock with AM/PM identifier.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

The output should be `"01/31/2015 12:01:01 PM"`

If you only want to send your date to the database as a standard DateTime variable, you shouldn't need to format it - SQL Server will look after that itself.

If you really find the culture to be a problem, you could programmatically set the thread's current culture like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You can read more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yeah, but it is getting converted to string. But, I want the format in datetime datatype only as because the sql server column datatype is datetime.

Comment: @Agnib can you show the code you are using when inserting the datetime values to the database, as well as the exact exception message you are getting, and place them in your question. have you tried saving the record without trying to format the datetime?

Comment: Ok. I will update the question with code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                            new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: This will get converted to string. If I again use Convert.ToDateTime on the string variable, its taking the value as it was. In Sql server, the column datatype has been set as datetime. So, I need to send datetime value only.